# How to set CHECK_POLICY OFF in the sql script

Tags: sql, sql-server

While installing our software in a HP laptop, we got a SQL error stating "The password does not meet windows policy requirements because it is too short."

When I checked, the local security policy in my machine has minimum 8 characters and in that laptop it has 12 characters. Our SQl password has 11 characters. That is why it is not installed in that laptop alone.

We can increase the password more than 12. But maybe in future the minimum password requirement can even change to 20 characters. So we thought of disabling the password check. Since I am new to this SQL, I don't know where to add the condition check. I have two SQL Script. The code snippet for the 2 scripts is shown below. Please let me know where to add it.

Script1:

```
ALTER LOGIN [sa] WITH PASSWORD=N'MSSql2008!'
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM syslogins 
                         WHERE name = 'teradyne')
BEGIN
    ALTER LOGIN [teradyne] WITH PASSWORD=N'SQL_PWD' 
END

GO
```

Script2:

```
GO

EXEC ('IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM syslogins 
                         WHERE name = ''clientsoftware'')
        EXEC sp_addlogin @loginame=''clientsoftware'', @passwd=''TER_SQL_PWD'' ')
GO

CHECKPOINT

GO
```

Where `SQL_PWD = software1!` for both scripts.

Please let me know where to add that CHECK_POLICY and also whether I need to add that CHECK_EXPIRATION

Comment: Why do you not want to set passwords that meet the policy?

Comment: Yes we can do that. Previously in our machine we had minimum 8 character support, so we given as 11. Now currently it is increased to 12.. We can change the password to increase more than 12. In future scope, the minimum password requirement might change. So for safety purpose, we can set the check_policy to off, so that it wont check for minimum password characters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the `ALTER LOGIN`  statement, you can use

```
ALTER LOGIN [teradyne] WITH PASSWORD=N'SQL_PWD' , CHECK_POLICY = OFF
```

You can't do it with the `sp_addlogin` procedure, and `CREATE LOGIN` is the preferred method.

If you need to use `sp_addlogin`, you could pre-hash the password, but I wouldn't recommend that to a beginner.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173768.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx

Comment: Instead of sp_addlogin can I use create login such that my syntax is CREATE LOGIN [clientsoftware] WITH PASSWORD = "TER_SQL_PWD", CHECK_POLICY = OFF

Comment: Thank you. One more thing. For the next release of our software we will modify the code. But for the current thing, our customer is not able to install the software because of this password restriction. He has no rights to go Local Security Policy to change the minimum password requirements. What workaround we need to do now to get rid from this..